# How do I identify the closed sets of a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-process

[image]

How do I identify the closed sets?

Comment: I've written my answers. but i'm not sure if they are correct.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: There is no state 4 in the matrix or diagram, so $\{1,2,3,4\}$ makes no sense as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your state transition diagram is correct. Your identification of Communicating classes is also correct. However, communicating classes can further be viewed as `closed` and `non-closed`. The communicating class $\{2,3\}$ is closed because if the process moves from state `1` to state`2`, it will never come back to the class$\{0,1\}$. The class $\{0,1\}$ is a non-closed communicating class because an escape from this class to the class $\{2,3\}$ is possible.

States belonging to closed communicating class are `recurrent` and those belonging to non-closed communicating class are `transient`.